# rest adapter not working in ember

Tags: ember.js, sails.js

i am trying to connect ember with sails , but it seems error in rest adapter

```js
 import DS from 'ember-data';

    import Ember from 'ember';
    import appConf from '../models/app-conf'

    export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
     // authorizer: 'authorizer:oauth2',
     namespace: 'api/v1',
     host: localhost:1337,
     // session: Ember.inject.service('session'),
     // headers: Ember.computed('session.isAuthenticated', function () {
     //  return {
     //   'authenticated': this.get('session.isAuthenticated')
     //  };
     // }),
     shouldReloadAll: function () { return true; },
     shouldBackgroundReloadRecord: function () { return false; },
     modelType: null,
        pathForType: function (type) {
            if (Ember.isNone(this.get("modelType")))
                throw this + ".modelType is not set!!!";
      return this.get("modelType");

     }
    });
```

whats wrong with ths code,
thank you in advance..

Comment: host must be contain http://

Comment: check the host ,it must be with http://

Answer (score 3):

it seems

```js
host: localhost:1337,
```

change it to

```js
host: 'http://localhost:1337',
```

Ember adapter only support http,htts..